# Extracting Key:Value pairs assoc with regex from string on Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string

```
server:all, nit:4545, search:dql has map
```

with the regular expression `/(\w+):((?:"[^"]*"|[^:,])*)/g` I get

```
["server:all", "nit:4545", "search:dql has map"] //Array
```

But I want to get

```
{server:"all","nit":"4545","search":"dql has map"}
```

OR

```
[{server:"all"},{"nit":"4545"},{"search":"dql has map"}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple regex for `key:value` and use a look using `exec`:

```js
var str = 'server:all, nit:4545, search:dql has map';
var re = /([\w-]+):([^,]+)/g;

var m;
var map = {};

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
  map[m[1]] = m[2];
}

console.log(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Use_an_inline_function_with_a_regular_expression_to_avoid_for_loops) to loop over the matches and captures and assign those to an empty object.

```js
const string = 'server:all, nit:4545, search:dql has map';
const regex = /(\w+):((?:"[^"]*"|[^:,])*)/g;
const map = {};

string.replace(regex, (m, c1, c2) => {
  map[c1] = c2;
});

console.log(map);
```

Comment: This does work, indeed, but using replace when you can just use the `regex#exec` without the need to modify the original string, seems unnecessary

Comment: @dquijada, the original string is not modified (did you try logging string after the replace). Also using `replace` for looping is a purpose of `replace`. The source I provided in my answer takes you to an example on the MDN docs of using replace for exactly this situation.

Answer (score 0):

For your example data, you could also first [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on a comma and then split on a colon:

```js
let str = "server:all, nit:4545, search:dql has map";
let result = {};
str.split(',').forEach(function(elm) {
  [k, v] = elm.trim().split(':');
  result[k] = v;
});

console.log(result);
```